# How to install a program for mac, from github (no brew)

Tags: macos, github, installation, build

I would like to play with Dima Kogan vnlog program for testing ; my computer is mac os.
There is a repository on Github hosting the code, with 3 branches, one of them named : build-osx.
https://github.com/dkogan/vnlog/branches

I dont see any file or documentation related to installation.
What would be the process to get it working on my computer (in such a way I would be able to uninstall it if needed) ? what are the tools needed ? That's something I have never never done yet.
(I don't have any git/subversion installed, if that matters).

**Edit1**, after first anwser.
Repository downloaded ; looks like "vnl-filter", "vnl-sort", "vnl-join" tools work ; yet "vnl-align" doesn't : `Can't locate Text/Table.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Text::Table module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level […]) at /Users/gilles/Downloads/vnlog-master/vnl-align line 5. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Users/gilles/Downloads/vnlog-master/vnl-align line 5.`
I believe some perl module is missing (or not found ?) for this tool. Any easy way to install it ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the current installation process ("**[Install on non-Debian boxes](https://github.com/dkogan/vnlog#install-on-non-debian-boxes)**") differs from the three-years old `build-osx` branch:

> Most of this is written in an interpreted language, so there’s nothing to build or install, and you can run the tools directly from the source tree:
>
> ```bash
> $ git clone https://github.com/dkogan/vnlog.git
> $ cd vnlog
> $ ./vnl-filter .....
> ```
>
> The python and perl libraries can be run from the tree by setting the `PYTHONPATH` and `PERL5LIB` environment variables respectively.
>
> For the C library, you should make, and then point your `CFLAGS` and `LDLIBS` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the local tree.

So if your Mac has the prerequisites set up, it should work after a clone.